# Using the Hessian, prove that affine scalar field is convex

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, hessian-matrix, scalar-fields

> Using the Hessian, prove that the affine scalar field $f : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ defined by $$f(x) = A^T x + b$$ where $A \in \Bbb R^n$ and $b \in \Bbb R$, is convex.

---

My intuition on this problem is to apply the theorem that if $f(x)$ is twice continuously differentiable then $f(x)$ is convex if and only if the Hessian is positive semidefinite, but I don't know how to find the hessian of this function and show that it is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Do you know how to compute the Hessian of a function?

Comment: I know it is to take the partial second derivative of this function with respect to x. but since this is a linear function so I suspect the hessian to be a zero matrix?

Comment: That's true, but you should not suspect, you should do the computation. What are the partial first derivatives of $f$?

Comment: @MaoWao it will be the sum of the element of A.  So the hessian will be a single value which is zero?

Comment: No, they are not. Btw, there are $n$ partial first derivatives, not just one. If it makes it easier for you, write down $f$ in terms of the components of $x$ and $A$, $b$.

Comment: @MaoWao Oh wait, so the partial first derivative will be a vector equal to A and the hessian will be a $nxn$ matrix of zero values?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

If $A^T=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ and $x=(x_1,...,x_n)^T$, then

$$f(x)=a_1x_1+...+a_nx_n+b.$$

Hence

$$f_{x_j}(x)=a_j$$

for $j=1,...,n.$

Conclusion: the hessian of this function $=?$

Comment: So the hessian will be a  $n*n$ zero matrix and it is positive semidefinite because the eigenvalues are all zero, then we reach the proof?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Element $\nabla^2 f_{ij}$ of the Hessian is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$. Because it's affine, this will be zero for each element, so the Hessian is a zero matrix. This is PSD *and* NSD, so an affine function is convex and concave.